# How to show parent table data and child table data in single column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables in SQL Server. The first table has a member name column, and the second table has their relatives name. I want to show data from both table in single column as like if member has any relatives then it must show immediately in second row after member name and if member don't has any relative then only one row must be appear. For example like below there is first table of memebrsname and their cityname

```
Regid        Name             City
----------------------------------------
1    Dr. Dharmesh Patel       New york
2    Dr. Vivek Patel          New york
3    Dr. Udayan Kachchhi      New york
4    Dr. Geeti Maheshwari     New york
5    Dr. SHANKAR DAYAL        Arizona
6    Dr. Tejas Kakkad         New york
7    Dr. TUSHAR PATEL         California
8    Dr. Arpan Shah           New york
9    Dr. AMI PATEL            New york
```

and `Relatives` table looks like this:

```
Regid   Name             City
-----------------------------------
6    MEETA KAKKAD        New york
1    Aditya Patel        New york
1    Namisha Patel       New york
3    Dimple Kachchhi     New york
4    Pankaj Maheshwari   New york
8    Agastya Shah        New york
8    Roma Shah           New york
```

And I want to show results like this:

```
regid        Name             City
---------------------------------------------
 1   Dr. Dharmesh Patel       New york
 1      Aditya Patel          New york
 1     Namisha Patel          New york

 2   Dr. Vivek Patel          New york
 3   Dr. Udayan Kachchhi      New york
 3       Dimple Kachchhi      New york
 4   Dr. Geeti Maheshwari     New york
 4      Pankaj Maheshwari     New york  
 5   Dr. SHANKAR DAYAL        Arizona
 6   Dr. Tejas Kakkad         New york
 6       MEETA KAKKAD         New york
 7   Dr. TUSHAR PATEL         California
 8   Dr. Arpan Shah           New york
 8       Agastya Shah         New york
 8       Roma Shah            New york

 9  Dr. AMI PATEL             New york
```

How can I get above result in SQL Server? Please help

Answer (score 1):

Use `row_number()` function with `union all` to get the child record under their parent record

```
select *,
         row_number() over (partition by Regid order by Sort) Seq
from
(
    select Regid, Name, City, 1 AS Sort from parent p 
    UNION ALL
    select Regid, Name, City, 2 AS Sort from child c 
)t
```

You could also define the explicit ordering

```
select Regid, Name, City, 1 AS Sort from parent p 
UNION ALL
select Regid, Name, City, 2 AS Sort from child c
order by  RegId, Sort
```

Comment: Instead of `row_number()` you should use `order by Regid, Sort`

Comment: @JamesZ... Right.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Regid,Name,City FROM
(
SELECT Regid,Name,City FROM PARENT
UNION
SELECT Regid,Name,City FROM CHILD
) AS T1
ORDER BY Regid
```

Answer (score 0):

seems you are looking for a union for both the tables ordered  by regid

```
select Regid, Name, City 
from table1 
union 
select Regid, Name, City 
from table2
order by regid
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you want to indent the names of the relatives.  Use `seq` to ensure the member appears before his/her relatives:

```
select Regid, Name, City
from
(
select 1 as seq, Regid, Name, City 
from table1 
union all
select 2, Regid,'    ' + Name, City 
from table2 ) t
order by seq, Regid
```